# How to convert list of lists into a dataframe while keeping track of list "number" innR?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of lists stored in `df_list` (sample code below). I want to convert it into a **dataframe** but I want to keep a **counter** `count` such that it tracks which list the data is from.

I want the end product to look something like this:

```
count   replicate level high.density low.density
1          1   low           54          36
1          1   low           54          31
1          2   low           11          28
1          2   low           11          45
1          1   mid           24          10
1          2   mid           12          24
1          2   mid           12          17
1          2    up           40           2
2          1   low           54          31
2          1   low           54          31
2          2   low           11          45
2          2   low           11          28
2          1   mid           24          10
2          2   mid           12          24
2          2    up           20           2
......
1000       2    up           40           5
```

#List of Lists code

```
df <- structure(list(replicate = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), level = c("low", "low", "mid", "mid", "low", "low", "mid", "mid", "up", "up", "up"), high.density = c(14, 54, 82, 24, 12, 11, 12, NA, 40, NA, 20), low.density = c(36, 31, 10, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        NA, 28, 45, 17, 24, 10, 5, 2)), class = c("spec_tbl_df","tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(replicate = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), level = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character","collector")), high.density = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double","collector")), low.density = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))

df$replicate <- as.factor(as.numeric(df$replicate))
df$level <- as.factor(as.character(df$level))
                      
df_shuffle <- function(DF) {
  my_split <- split(DF, f = ~ DF$replicate + DF$level)
  shuffle <- lapply(my_split, \(x) {
    nrX <- nrow(x)
    cbind(x[, c('replicate', 'level')],
          high.density = x[sample(seq_len(nrX), replace = TRUE), 'high.density'],
          low.density = x[sample(seq_len(nrX), replace = TRUE), 'low.density'])
  })
  DF_new <- do.call(rbind, shuffle)
  rownames(DF_new) <- NULL
  return(DF_new)
}

B <- 1000
df_list <- replicate(B, df_shuffle(df), simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: Is `df_list` what you're trying to convert to a data frame? If so, skip the bulk of the code here and just give us a sample (not all 1000 values) of it; that lets us pick up working at the point where the question starts, as well as bypassing the fact that randomized data without a seed set won't recreate the same each time. If not, it's unclear what your code is doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, we can simply utilize `data.table::rbindlist()` function:

```
library(data.table)

rbindlist(df_list, idcol = 'count')

#        count replicate level high.density low.density
#     1:     1         1   low           14          31
#     2:     1         1   low           14          31
#     3:     1         2   low           12          45
#     4:     1         2   low           12          45
#     5:     1         1   mid           24          NA
#    ---                                               
# 10996:  1000         2   mid           NA          17
# 10997:  1000         2   mid           NA          17
# 10998:  1000         2    up           20          10
# 10999:  1000         2    up           20           5
# 11000:  1000         2    up           40           2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can add a column containg the index or the names of the list elements with `dplyr::bind_rows` by specifying the `.id` argument. If the list has names `bind_rows` will add those, otherwise it will take the index (we can't choose which one `bind_rows` should take).

```r
df_list %>% 
  bind_rows(., .id = "count")
```

If we want to go beyond that, or if the list has names and we want to use the index instead, we can use `purrr::imap` and pipe the result into `bind_rows`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

imap(df_list,
     ~ mutate(.x,
              count = .y, 
              .before = "replicate")) %>% 
  bind_rows()

#>       count replicate level high.density low.density
#> 1         1         1   low           14          31
#> 2         1         1   low           14          36
#> 3         1         2   low           11          45
#> 4         1         2   low           12          28
#> 5         1         1   mid           24          10
#> 6         1         1   mid           24          10
#> 7         1         2   mid           12          17
#> 8         1         2   mid           NA          17
#> 9         1         2    up           40           5
#> 10        1         2    up           20           5
#> 11        1         2    up           20           5
#> 12        2         1   low           14          31
#> 13        2         1   low           54          31
#> ...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

In `imap` we create a new column for each `data.frame` `.x` with `mutate`. The new column is called `count` and `.y` is the index of each list element. We use `mutate`s `.before` argument to make this column the first column of each `data.frame`. The result of the call to  `imap` is a list of `data.frame`s which we merge together into one large `data.frame` with `dplyr::bind_rows`.